# iOS Group Photo Library photos by categories

Tags: ios, swift, phasset, photosframework

In my app I am getting all photos(`PHAsset`) using this code

```
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            print("Good to proceed")
            let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
            let allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
            print("Found \(allPhotos.count) images")
        case .denied, .restricted:
            print("Not allowed")
        case .notDetermined:
            print("Not determined yet")
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
```

I have two questions:

1. Can I get grouped photos by categories from Photo Library? (see image below)
2. Can I group photos by categories in my side? (see image below)

[image]

Comment: How would the computer know which photos are flowers and which ones are animals?

Comment: @matt Apple completes it by image recognization.

Comment: @matt Are you understand my question?

Answer (score 1):

**It seems not can implement it directly.**

But,you can classify by system smart album、moments or album(the result is PHAssetCollection type).

**Swift 5**

Smart Album

```
let systemAlbums = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .albumRegular, options: nil)
```

Moments

```
let systemAlbums = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .moment, subtype: .albumRegular, options: nil)
```

Album

```
let systemAlbums = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .albumRegular, options: nil)
```

and also can display the user's album(the fetch result is a PHCollection type that contained user collections)

```
let userAlbums = PHCollectionList.fetchTopLevelUserCollections(with: nil)
```

**Besides:**
You needn't request authorization every time, the system will alert the user and request authorization at your first call every related function.

There is a sample code about browsing photos.[Browsing and Modifying Photo Albums](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/browsing_and_modifying_photo_albums)

Comment: thanks for answer, but this is not what i wanted. If you go Photos app and select Search tab, there have grouped photos by categories, see image in question (Animals, Playgrounds, Flowers, ... etc). I want get that collections.

Comment: @Karen Hovhannisyan, oh, sorry, I've not looked at the image carefully, I think there are no such functions to complete directly, Apple maybe completes it by image recognization.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Public API to access the categories in 3rd party apps at the moment.