# Is there a way to access photo category metadata in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, photokit

In the Photos app or in the ImagePicker there is a search which helps select images of a certain type like “food”, “plate”, “breakfast”, etc. I wonder if I can somehow load all food photos into the app automatically when the user gives permission to their library.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2weE.jpg)

Comment: Short version: it seems there is no way. For more info, look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56390767/ios-group-photo-library-photos-by-categories

Comment: Machine Learning is the key